# How do I make my animation smoother Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, ondraw

I have an app that has a ball running across the screen. When the ball is halfway the application records some audio, computes the FFT and does some extra analysis.

This is handled by Asynctask, however the animation still briefly stutters.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make it run smoother?

Thanks

code below:

```
import com.ben.applicationLayer.GameView;
import dataObjectLayer.Sprite;
import dataObjectLayer.MusicalNote;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource;
import android.media.AudioFormat; 
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class recorderThread extends AsyncTask<Sprite, Void, Integer> {

short[] audioData;
int bufferSize;    
Sprite ballComp;

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Sprite... ball) {

    MusicalNote note = ball[0].expectedNote;
    ballComp = ball[0];
        boolean recorded = false; 
        double frequency;
        int sampleRate = 8192;  
        AudioRecord recorder = instatiateRecorder(sampleRate);
        double[] magnitude = new double[1024];
        double[] audioDataDoubles = new double[2048];

        while (!recorded) {  //loop until recording is running

        if (recorder.getState()==android.media.AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) 
// check to see if the recorder has initialized yet.
        {
            if (recorder.getRecordingState()==android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED)
                  recorder.startRecording();  
//check to see if the Recorder has stopped or is not recording, and make it record.                               
            else {             
               double max_index;
               recorder.read(audioData,0,bufferSize);   
//read the PCM audio data into the audioData array

               computeFFT(audioDataDoubles, magnitude);

               max_index = getLargestPeakIndex(magnitude);

               frequency = getFrequencyFromIndex(max_index, sampleRate);

            //checks if correct frequency, assigns number
               int correctNo = correctNumber(frequency, note);

checkIfMultipleNotes(correctNo, max_index, frequency, sampleRate, magnitude, note);

               if (audioDataIsNotEmpty())
                   recorded = true;
               if (correctNo!=1)
                   return correctNo;
              }
        }
        else
        {
            recorded = false;
            recorder = instatiateRecorder(sampleRate);
        }
    }

        if (recorder.getState()==android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) 
        {
            killRecorder(recorder);
        }

        return 1;
}


private void killRecorder(AudioRecord recorder) {
    recorder.stop(); //stop the recorder before ending the thread
    recorder.release(); //release the recorders resources
    recorder=null; //set the recorder to be garbage collected
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {  
    (result == 2)
        GameView.score++;
    }

private AudioRecord instatiateRecorder(int sampleRate) {    
        bufferSize= AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)*2;
 //get the buffer size to use with this audio record

AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord (AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,bufferSize); //instantiate the AudioRecorder

    audioData = new short [bufferSize]; //short array that pcm data is put into.         
        return recorder;
}

}
```

Comment: Show us the code around calling this AsyncTask because the problem is not here. AsyncTask does its job on a different thread so it should not affect the Animation (in concept but might though if this is extreme). Anyway please show us the animation code and the place where you call this AsyncTask

Answer (score 3):

Using an Asynctask is along the lines of what you want to do. However, I would suggest using a thread-pool. You can then put your animation in as a task, add your audio recording as a task, the FFT as another task, and your additional analysis as a task.

The brief stutter is likely the result of allocating resources for the recording in the animation thread. Using a pool means you won't have to pause while creating the thread to run your audio tasks. Obviously, some code would be handy to fully understand your problem.

Take a look at:

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

or

ThreadPoolExecutor
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

A very simple example of what you might want to do:

In your activity you can define this to start up the tasks

```
ExecutorService threadPool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);
Recording record = new Recording();
Ball ball = new Ball(threadPool, record);
threadPool.submit(ball);
```

Ball.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

public class Ball implements Runnable { 
    private final Recording record;
    private final ExecutorService threadPool;

    private boolean condition;  
    private boolean active;

    public Ball(ExecutorService threadPool, Recording record) {
        this.record = record;
        this.threadPool = threadPool;
        this.active = true;
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        while (this.active) {
            moveBall();
            if (isBallHalfway()) {
                threadPool.submit(record);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isBallHalfway() {
        return condition; // Condition for determining when ball is halfway
    }

    private void moveBall() {
        // Code to move the ball
    }
}
```

Recording.java

```
public class Recording implements Runnable {
    @Override public void run() {
        // Do recording tasks here
    }
}
```

Comment: I have included the code, thanks for your response. looking at the code, what type of threading would you think is best?

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I've added some code showing how to approach the problem using a ThreadPool. This should give you an idea, feel free to ask more questions if you need it explained further. :)

Answer (score 1):

As Mohammed says, it's hard to guess what the problem might be without seeing the code. With that in mind...

It sounds like your `AsyncTask` might be blocking other threads from executing. Make sure you have some calls to `Thread.sleep()` in there to give the scheduler chance to switch back to the UI thread (`Thread.yield()` is also an option, but be aware there are some gotchas with yield).

Comment: I have now included the code, where would i include the sleep methods? and should i bother with yield?

Comment: `yield` is best avoided if you're at all unsure what you're doing. Without knowing how long each of those method calls takes I'm going to have to guess, but I'd say that a good candidate for where to put the calls to `sleep` would be at the end of your while loop. If the `computeFFT()` function is slow (it may be 'fast', but if memory serves FFTs still involve quite a lot of work) you might want to look at placing some calls to `sleep()` within that too.

Answer (score 0):

without code it will be hard to guess with can optimize, but I will tell you what I did with more than 1 million operations in loading ..
• If you have problem with performance, try :
1-check your data type of variables and set lower in case you are sure variable doesn't need more byte, i.e. for size you short instead of int.

2-check your code and try to get all results can be stored for next launch, and call them next time instead of calculating them again.

• But if your problem that animation is slow and you have no problem with memory, so try reduce period of animation or increase units of movements.

by the way how do you implement the animation? frame-by-frame animation, or layout animation, or view animation ?

Comment: If you're optimizing for speed, #1 is actually a bad idea! The JVM converts bytes, shorts and chars to ints before performing any arithmetic operations, so using e.g. shorts is at best the same, and at worst slower than using ints.

Comment: you are right, and me too .. I was mentioning to storage efficiency and you are talking about run-time performance. so in such as case with our fellow Ben Taliadoros, I would agree with you :-) that there is no big deal to user lower data type... + to your comment Baqueta, and thnx for info

Comment: Thanks for the replies, was interesting. I have included my code now to show you, in answer to your question Mohammed, its frame by frame. any ideas?