# When drawing a bitmap or some bitmaps on a Canvas upon starting an Activity, the drawing time has spikes

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

This is the code I use to draw a bitmap on a canvas which is shown in a 1080x1080 ImageView:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
animCanvas.drawBitmap(animateNext, currentRect, viewportRect, animCanvasPaint);
Log.i("draw_time", (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "");
```

Said code is within a ValueAnimator of 2500 ms duration.

When I executed this code right after starting the activity this code is in (a.k.a. running the ValueAnimator for the first time), the draw_time can mostly be 2-4 ms, but sometimes it would spike to more than 33 ms, causing some lag.

However, when running the ValueAnimator the second time and afterwards, the spikes don't occur. I know it's just a momentary problem, but I'm more focused on the first time with the spikes.

Why do the spikes happen, and how can they be removed entirely or their impact reduced?

Edit: Before animating the images, I used an AsyncTask to grab the images from the SD card or memory cache and android-gpuimage to filter the images. Changing the Executor to AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR from AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is other things slowing down your code (you're doing too much on the main thread), depending on what you're doing, enabling hardware acceleration may be a bad idea.

Comment: Is there another thread or AsyncTask going on?  You may be sharing the CPU and get context switched away from.  Or it could be a garbage collection spike.  I don't see anything with your code that's optimizable.

Comment: @Ali I'm trying to emulate a video with UI animation, actually. Is that one of the cases where Hardware Accel is a bad idea?

Comment: Yes, I think that might be a bad idea. Hardware acceleration in my understanding works best when there is a static image that is moving. Thought, you're probably best going on Google+ and asking the Android Developers group! However, [take a look at this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976039/how-do-i-make-my-animation-smoother-android).